# Store enum values into separate Oracle attributes using JPA

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, enums

In my rest API I'm taking a response from user from checkboxes in a survey, like:
*Appealing, Easy to use, etc*.

In the response object I'm converting this value to an `Enum`, like:

```
class enum CheckboxResponse {
    APPEALING("Appealing"),
    EASY_TO_USE("Easy to use");

    ...
}
```

I want to store these values in DB. So I'm think for each checkbox there should be a separate attribute in table.

```
create table survey_data {
    .....
    APPEALING NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    EASY_TO_USE NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    ...
}
```

My response DTO looks like:

```
public class ResponseDTO {
    ...
    List<CheckboxResponse> checkboxResponses;
    ...
}
```

As it is coming in the list I don't want to loop over list & check each enum value is present or not.

Is there a more effective way to save these values in hibernate?

Comment: Why are you using an `enum` here? It sounds like you need a set of `boolean` fields instead of an `enum`.

Comment: ...or a `Map<CheckboxResponse,Boolean>`. If the set of options does not really change, why not map it to an object like `Checks { boolean isAppealing; boolean isEasyToUse; etc }`, that is very easy to map with `@Embeddable`.